# How come when I try to install Python 3.4, MySQL doesn't recognize as it a requirement met?

Tags: mysql

This is a picture of the problem that I am having when I go and check if Python 3.4 meets the requirement after I already installed it on Operating System:

[image]

Comment: You probably need to add it to your class path.

Comment: do i go into system environment to do that?

Comment: Yes. "system variables" iirc. If you google "python system variables", I imagine they'll be guides for this.

Comment: I went into the system environment and added this:                                                                                                                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin; C:\Python34;

Comment: After downloading Python 3.4 and adding the correct directory above, MySQL still didn't recognized as requirement met. What is wrong? Any suggestions?